# After running git init, all files named index.js are automatically ignored, also .gitignore does not work at all

Tags: git, macos

On macOS Big Sur:

This started recently. After running git init on any terminal, regardless of the project. I was using Git 2.35.1 installed with homebrew at first, then Git 2.30.1 Apple Git-130. Same issues.

Reinstalling Git 2.35.1 has no effect at all. Afaik uninstalling Git 2.30.1 Apple Git-130 is a no-no. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have a global .gitignore file in your user profile folder?

Comment: Yes I do, and after deleting it, everything went back to normal. Reinstalled git 2.35.1 with brew. Same result. Thank you.